# Sharing EF 6.0 PCL in Webapp, xamarin Monotouch IPAD?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, xamarin.ios, xamarin

We've developed a webapplication using EF 6 Model first. This model with its businesslogic is in a seperate PCL project. Is it possible to use the compiled dll in a Xamarin.monotouch application using a local DB? If yes, how? Does anyone know a nice article on this subject? If not, does anyone know a workaround for this matter?

I've tried a google search but did not find any relevant results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two scenarios - Code First or Model First. Both come down to conditional compilation.

**Code First** is much easier:

- Create your EF project (√ done)
- Create another (PCL) project where you import the same model classes for compilation. Make that other project of the PCL type you need.
- In the PCL project add a compiler symbol. Find that in project options/build/compiler[Define Symbols] in Xamarin studio. Add a new symbol, such as "PCL"

In your EF code surround all the items that don't compile with

```
#if !PCL
  public DbSet<Users> {...}
#endif
```

You can also add code that would only show up in the PCL or have alternative definitions:

```
#if !PCL
  public ICollection<User> Users{get;set;}
#endif
#if PCL
  public List<User> Users{get;set;}
#endif
```

The much more difficult scenario is **Model First**:

- Create a database
- Create a **new project** with EF from your database
- Find your .edmx file and expand everything under it.
- there are two .tt files - Model.Context.tt and Model.tt. Under Model.tt you should see all the generated .cs files
- Optional step: Install yourself a T4 VS addin for code highlighting while editing .tt files
- [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) you can think of as Razor or some of the similar templating techniques out there. Familiarize yourself with the template by looking for generated C# keywords/classes such as `class` or `using` or `namespace` or `ICollection`
- You can edit the template and as soon as you save the file it will regenerate the .cs files. I usually have both the template and a generated file open side-by-side so I can see the result immediately.
- find the places in your Model.tt that generate things that don't compile or aren't of the type you need them to be.
- Modify Model.tt as described below.
- Create a new PCL project with the settings you want for target devices
- Close VS/XS, copy the EF project a new file and open it with notepad
- Open the PCL project and copy it's top `<PropertyGroup>`, replace the EF-copy project's top property group with that. There are settings there that make the project a PCL, including `<TargetFrameworkProfile>`
- copy the `<Import Project=...>` tag from the new PCL project into the EF-copy project, replacing the existing one
- In the EF-copy project remove all references to anything but .cs files
- Open the solution with VS/XS again, add the copied project to the solution and add PCL to its compiler symbols, change its output location or file name to indicate it's PCL. I change the name of the library to library.pcl.dll

**T4 Code Modification**: In my own .tt I have edited the original around line 50, where the constructor is generated

```
if (collectionNavigationProperties.Any()){
        #>
 #if !PCL
<#
foreach (var navigationProperty in collectionNavigationProperties)
{
#>
  this.<#=code.Escape(navigationProperty)#> = new HashSet<<#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType())#>>();
<# } #>
#endif
<#
}
```

and then around line 100, where the class properties are generated

```
#if !PCL
<# // this looks like the original .tt
        foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.NavigationProperty(navigationProperty)#>
<#
        }
#>

#endif
#if PCL
<# // and this is the copy I've added. Notice it calls a different method, see below
        foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.DeserializeNavigationProperty(navigationProperty)#>
<#
        }
#>

#endif
```

After the `NavigationProperty` method in the .tt I've added this:

```
public string DeserializeNavigationProperty(NavigationProperty navigationProperty)
{
    string navPropCode = NavigationProperty(navigationProperty);
    navPropCode = navPropCode.Replace("ICollection","List");
    return navPropCode;
}
```

replacing the `ICollection` with `List` way I have a concrete type to deserialize into.

Comment: Thnx for your response! +1 Except we've been using the Model first approach.. can it still be done like this?

Comment: @MarkRijsmus here you go

Comment: Thnx for all the information, we will try this out. I gave you as much points as i could possibly give. Thnx for taking the time to answer my question! Greetings.

Comment: updated the answer with a step to replace the project's top PropertyGroup with one from a PCL project